# Update a cloned repository from Github?

Tags: github

Can I update a cloned repository from Github by `sudo apt-get update`? How is this update different from an update using `git pull`?

Answer (score 1):

No. To work with `git` (and Github), you can learn from [this tutorial](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Git/article.html).

`sudo apt-get update` is used to update the packages information of your OS (Ubuntu). `sudo` is used to attribute superuser level to your current user; `apt-get` is the package manager of your OS; `update` is the `apt-get` command to update the packages information.